# Angularjs validate JWT

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jwt

I have tried implementing JWT to my Angularjs application for a secured authentication. I have generated the JWT at server side(java) and the implementation returns a JWT to the client side after a successful login. I have stored the JWT in  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization and also in the $window.sessionStorage. Now I could see the JWT in all all requests made by the $http service.

The part I am not clear is I dont know how to proceed from this point. What I guess is I should validate the JWT from now on for all $http calls at the server side somehow. Can someone clarify me how I should proceed for validating the client side JWT at the server side ?

Comment: What's on the server side? Rails? Node?

Comment: sorry I didnt mention that, it is java

Comment: What you do is to add some identification about the current user in the token, and on every request, you get the value from the `Authorization` header and parse it - Then you check the which user was encoded in the token and associate the current request to them. You can debug the token [here](https://jwt.io/) by the token and the secret key (available only on the server). note that you should not encode private information and put as little as possible information in it so you won't get a huge token. Also it's recommended to pass it over secured connection (HTTPS)

Comment: @SGN Well if it was rails i could fire in some code but alas - tis not!

Answer (score 1):

Yes every time the client makes a request to the backend, you now have to supply the JWT in the header.
Inside the JWT you can have some parameters that identifies the user, like his username for example. Do not store password or other sensitive information inside the JWT.

[image]

If you are useing Java, you could create a [Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that will be mapped to a url that only an authorized user can have acces. In the filter you can make the necessary checks to see if the suplied token is correct, if it is you can let the request pass trough, otherwise you can return to the client an error specifying that he does not have access.

If you need more information, may be [this is a good place to start](https://jwt.io/introduction/).

Comment: Still I dont have an idea to implement step 56 and step 6 given in the above picture. any idea or blogs on that ?